# asp.net scriptbundle multiple include vs single include

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification, scriptbundle

What is the difference in bundling:

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
  .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js","file2.js", "file3.js"));
```

vs

```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
                .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
                .Include("file2.js")
                .Include("file3.js"));
```

I can put many scripts inside the ONE include method or I can use many include methods.

When should I use what?

Answer (score 4):

Either choice is fine, it is a syntax, readability choice. `Include("resource1", "resource2", "resourceN")` is simple overload of the Include method that uses the `params` keyword. In C# the `params` keyword allows for a variable number of parameters.

`Include('Resource1").Include("Resource2").Include("ResourceN")` is a different signature of Include method that accepts one string argument. Include("resource1").Include("resource2") is simple chaining.

Either syntax ultimately calls the same code to add the "resource" string paths. You are just calling different signature/overloaded definitions of the Include method to pass your string resouce/js arguments.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.

In both ways you create a new [ScriptBundle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.scriptbundle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance named "~/bundles/jquery" that includes all the files in the Scripts folder that match the wild card string "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js" and also "file2.js", "file3.js". Then you add the [ScriptBundle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.scriptbundle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance to the [BundleCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundlecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance named `bundles` using the [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundlecollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

The {version} wild card matching shown above is used to automatically create a jQuery bundle with the appropriate  version of jQuery in your Scripts folder.  Allows you to use NuGet to update to a newer jQuery version without changing the preceding bundling code or jQuery references in your view pages.

---

For more info refer to [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).

Answer (score 0):

The choice is based on preference as the first option uses an overloaded method of the Include operation, accepting multiple parameters whereas the second option simply chains the values.

Very similar to using either of two styles of writing LINQ queries... all comes down to your preference.